# How to disable HttpOnly flag on Set-Cookie header on login in Spring Boot 2.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, tomcat8

I am having issues disabling the httpOnly flag on the set-cookie header. This is mainly an issue on login when the JSESSIONID is being sent back in the response. Note that this is on a tomcat server deployed on AWS EBS.

Any of the configs below work fine locally but no on deployment.

I have tried the following solutions, none seem to work

application.yml config

```
server:  
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        http-only: false
```

Servlet Context Initializer

```
@Bean
open fun servletContextInitializer(): ServletContextInitializer {
    return ServletContextInitializer { servletContext ->
        servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(setOf(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE))
        val sessionCookieConfig = servletContext.sessionCookieConfig
        sessionCookieConfig.isHttpOnly = false
    }
```

WebServerFactoryCustomizer

```
@Bean
open fun tomcatCustomizer(): WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {
    return WebServerFactoryCustomizer { tomcat ->
        tomcat
            .addContextCustomizers(TomcatContextCustomizer { context -> context.useHttpOnly = false })
    }
```

web.xml

```
    <session-config>
      <cookie-config>
        <http-only>false</http-only>
      </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

Sample Request Header

```
Host: 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: 
Authorization: Bearer null
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 58
Origin: 
Connection: keep-alive
TE: Trailers
```

Sample Response Header

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
date: Sat, 16 Mar 2019 14:11:58 GMT
set-cookie: AWSALB=qBpX9uFjtkP4H7gyJ3EXL8na0a7aARiEN/twi0cc2sPywvbysKXXaNfQbe8HaS5hcC6VRnkp09VYj0pGcXiHbWRod9OithDlQ0ZIvHSbY7B5xiJT1r8N+lcRdCcp; Expires=Sat, 23 Mar 2019 14:11:57 GMT; Path=/
server: Apache/2.4.37 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers
access-control-allow-origin: 
access-control-allow-credentials: true
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: DENY
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=70F12355ABFDD0F42292D9F6CEAA22BF; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: How are you deploying your application on AWS, as a *jar* or *war inside tomcat* ?

Comment: war file using EBS deploy

Comment: With the load balancer. Unfortunately, the load balancer isn't something that I can disable/bypass. Would the load balancer affect the JSESSIONID set-cookie?

Comment: @dur works fine on local tomcat. Could be some configuration in AWS Application Load Balancer? One thing to note, SSL is terminated at the Load Balancer. The connection between the Load Balancer and the instance is HTTP only. However, Secure flag gets added to the JSESSIONID set-cookie

Comment: @dur yes you're right. However, the Secure flag raises the question of whether the load balancer might have some rules in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve it by creating a Filter that runs as part of Spring Security. The filter executes before the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, thus waiting until the set-cookie header is added then updates the headers (before in the chain, gets last call after doFilter() executes).

Filter Implementation

```
package com.zambezii.app.security.filter

import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean
import java.io.IOException
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

class SessionFilter : GenericFilterBean() {

    @Throws(IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        val req = request as HttpServletRequest
        val res = response as HttpServletResponse
        chain.doFilter(req, res)

        removeHttpOnlyFlag(res)
    }

    private fun removeHttpOnlyFlag(res: HttpServletResponse) {
        val setCookieHeaderName = "set-cookie"
        var setCookieHeader = res.getHeader(setCookieHeaderName)

        if (setCookieHeader != null) {
            setCookieHeader = setCookieHeader.replace("; HttpOnly", "")
            res.setHeader(setCookieHeaderName, setCookieHeader)
        }
    }
}
```

Security Config

```
open class WebSecurityConfig() : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
            ...
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .addFilterBefore(SessionFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter::class.java)
```